# running using xampp error on ubuntu : Fatal error: Call to a member function rowCount() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I'm testing a program running well using `xampp` and `Windows 7`,
But when i'm upload to the server using `Ubuntu` (`mysql`, `php`, `apache` using `apt-get`) it's getting error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function rowCount() on a non-object in /var/www/siarsip/class/user.php on line 56

Here the code snipped :

```html
function getAllUser(){
  $query=$this->db1->query("SELECT a.user_id,a.username,a.password,a.NIP,a.role,b.category,a.input_date,a.last_update FROM users as a RIGHT JOIN user_categories as b ON a.role=b.usercat_id ORDER BY role");
  $jml_data=$query->rowCount();
  if($jml_data>=1){
   $hasil=$query->fetchAll(); //line 56
   return $hasil;
  }else{
   return $jml_data;
  }
 }
```

I've tried to change line 56 to :

```
if(!empty($query) AND $jml_data > 0) {
```

Still not working.

update : 
Using @cjriii code, i've update line 56 to using this :

```
if(is_object($query))
```

{
  {
   code here
    }

}

Now there's no error, i've tried to login produces same error 
"Fatal error: Call to a member function rowCount() on a non-object in /var/www/siarsip/class/user.php on line 74"

```html
 function loginUser($username,$password){
  $password_md5=md5($password); 
  $query=$this->db1->query("SELECT*FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password_md5'");
  if(is_object($query))
{
  $hasil=$query->rowCount(); //line 74
  return $hasil;
 }
}
```

I've insert the code again to line 74 
if(is_object($query))
{

Produces no error.
But now i cannot login using the username and password that usually works.

Need another advice bro..

Comment: any frameworks using??

Comment: @Abdulla, no bro just usign native php

Comment: using pdo class or peo php??

Comment: @Abdulla not using pdo class. And about peo php, what is that? I never knew..

Comment: you can use `count` function and `mysql fetch array` function

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

Test if $query is an object before calling a method on it. Thats' where the error comes from.

Second, instead of testing for !empty($query), try testing for is_object($query).

```
if(is_object($query))
{
    $jml_data = $query->rowCount();
    if($jml_data >= 1)
    {
        //rest of your code here
    }
    else
        return $jml_data;
}
```

Edit:

Please check the documention on empty(): Your call may be returning a valid value for empty to return false.

http://php.net/empty
http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-object.php

Comment: HI cjriii, Thanks for the fast respond. Now it works but produced another error on the other line. I've change it it works. But i cannot login using the username and password. *can i insert code in the comment or i should write it in the aswer question?

Comment: HI cjriii, can you help me again with this new problem? I can't login after i update the script..